# ruby on rails, search results to json array (jbuilder)

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, jbuilder

I'm new to rails and I just have a quick question...

I have a calendar gem which currently pulls event data from json as such (viewings/index.json.jbuilder)

```
json.array!(@viewings) do |viewing|
  json.extract! viewing, :id, :room_id, :user_id, :start_time, :end_time, :notes
  json.title viewing.user.name
  json.start viewing.start_time
  json.end viewing.end_time
  json.url viewing_url(viewing, format: :html)
end
```

anyway, I have created a search feature on my "viewings" index page, where a user selects the room from a drop-down and it displays the corresponding viewings.

However, I need to make a JSON array from the results of the search, so it can be fed to the calendar.

I know I can achieve this by doing something like, which does work:

```
@viewings = Viewing.where(room_id: 1 )
```

but obviously I want to pass a variable in to that line of code, something like

```
@viewings = Viewing.where(room_id: params[:search_string] )
```

The search string will always be a room ID, but the above code (and any variations I can think of) don't seem to work.

OR can I make a JSON array from my search output. my search is as so...

```
  def search
    @rooms = Room.all
        @viewings = Viewing.simple_search(params[:search_string])
        render :action => "index"
  end
```

Can anyone help?!

EDIT:

I'm still struggling with this one a lot. I had a look at the jquery page below but its still not doing what I hoped.

I have simplified the function in my viewings controller as so:

```
  def rmselect
    @query1 = params[:rmno]
    @rooms = Room.all
        @viewings=Room.find(params[:rmno]).viewings
    render :action => "index"
  end
```

And I have created an _rmselect.json.jbuilder as so:

```
@viewings = Viewing.where(room_id: @query1 )
json.array!(@viewings) do |viewing|

  json.title viewing.user.name
  json.start viewing.start_time
  json.end viewing.end_time

end
```

I was hoping the `@query1` variable would be passed into the jbuilder page which would cause it only to display viewings for the selected room. However, it seems that jbuilder cannot see any variables unless they are in `def index` (where it's no good).

I also can't understand why `_rmselect.json.jbuilder` is taking the `@viewings.all` from `def index`, rather then the `@viewings=Room.find(params[:rmno]).viewings` from `def rmselect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I suppose the situation is like that:

Viewing model:

```
class Viewing < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   belongs_to :room
   ...
end
```

Room model:

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   has_many :viewings
   ...
end
```

Retrive viewings from room id, you can do something like:

```
@viewings=Room.find(params[:search_string]).viewings
```

For create JSON array of result, render jbuilder view who contains something like that:

```
# @people = People.all

json.array! @people, :id, :name

  # => [ { "id": 1, "name": "David" },      { "id": 2, "name": "Jamie" } ]
```

I report an example of official jbuilder [docs](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/blob/master/README.md) I think you can use  json.array with viewings:

```
json.array! @viewings, field1, field2, ...
```

Otherwise you can use this in your controller:

```
render json: @viewings
```

but if you've used jbuilder, I think it's better you continue that way.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to reply. Unfortunately your link seems to be dead, and I'm not sure how to do the find.

Comment: I suppose who params[:search_string] is an array of Ids and look like: [1,2,3]. If i suppose right find method return an array of objects.

Comment: If search_string is a Json array string you can use this [library](http://flori.github.io/json/) for parse string, then use find.

Comment: sorry its probably my fault for explaining it badly but search_string isn't the json array, that's the input from the select field. what I need to extract is the results after the search here  `code`@viewings = Viewing.simple_search(params[:search_string])"`code`

Comment: Ok, if you have room_id you can search this room and retrieve viewings: `@viewings=Room.find(params[:search_string]).viewings`

Comment: Ok that's great, that works fine, but any idea how I can create a JSON array of the results yielded from @viewings=Room.find(params[:search_string]).viewings

Comment: thanks again for the help. still having issues, if you could have a look at my edit to see where I am going wrong, that would be great!

Comment: If you call `render action: ...` is performed index action of current controller. Why you call render action? I can suppose  you wanted call only index view, if so you can use `render 'index'`

Comment: Thanks, I've changed that now but it hasn't helped, my jbuilder is still creating an array for `@viewings.all` rather than the `@viewings=Room.find(params[:search_string]).viewings` that I want it too?